# get fraction part of a decimal number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get a fraction part of a decimal number in rails. For example I have a number, that "1.23" and I want to get "23" It is may be too easy but, does anyone have any idea about how can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the easiest way to do it - but you can simply split the number using "." character - like this:

```
number = 1.23
parts = number.to_s.split(".")
result = parts.count > 1 ? parts[1].to_s : 0
```

Comment: Future readers, please don't use this approach. It may work in a simplistic case, but will trip in any locale-aware scenario. Although not very error-prone in Ruby which hardcodes `.` as the floating point delimiter, it would promote the bad habit to be used with other, less forgiving languages. Please use math functions for math operations, see answers below.

Answer (score 65):

Try to use modulo method:

```
1.23.modulo(1) => 0.23
```

Read more here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-modulo

Or you can convert float to integer and substract it from original float value.

```
1.23 - 1.23.to_i => 0.23
```

Comment: I get `(1.1).modulo(1) # 0.10000000000000009` which is less than acceptable!

Comment: And I get 1.234 - 1.234.to_i # 0.2399999999999999 which is less than acceptable. This is typical of floating point arithemetic. So is EfratBlaier's .to_s way the best then?

Comment: @labyrinth I am using `n.modulo(1).round(2)`

Comment: @labyrinth I'd suggest using the BigDecimal type if floating point errors aren't acceptable. The accepted String-based answer is really just a dirty hack.

Comment: This answer did not handle negative numbers the way I expected. See my answer below

Answer (score 10):

```
n = 1.23

n.modulo(1)
=> 0.22999999999999998

n - n.to_i
=> 0.22999999999999998
```

Recommended read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Fixed the typo of `to.i` -> `to_i`.

Answer (score 6):

if you know your desired precision, this might be a tad faster to to_s solution.

```
1.1234.modulo(1).round(4) #0.1234
```

Answer (score 6):

Deciding on the proper solution requires understanding the type that you're working with. If your values are Float (the standard type for non-whole numbers in Ruby) then logically correct answers like `mod(1)` may produce unexpected results due to [floating point errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples). For any case where Float is the proper data type to be using in the first place, this is likely acceptable.

If floating point errors are *not* acceptable, don't use `Float`! Ruby comes with the great [`BigDecimal`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) class which is much more accurate at the cost of performance and a slightly more verbose syntax.

```
decimal = BigDecimal.new("1.23")
decimal.frac #=> 0.23
```

Answer (score 2):

> ..."1.23" and I want to get "23".

Just remove the integer part and multiply per 100.

```
((number - number.to_i) * 100).to_i
```

Comment: This introduces imprecision, so I would not recommend this approach. Example: (37319.70 - 37319.70.to_i) * 100 = 69.99999999970896

Answer (score 1):

```
 a=1.23 #value of a will be 1.23
 a=a-a.to_i #value of a will be 0.23
```

Comment: Again, as zephos2014 says, it brings in imprecision; it produces 0.22999999999999998

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways we can achieve the output `modulo` is one of them

`1.23.modulo(1) => 0.22999999999999998`

you can round the result as per your convenience

but to achieve what you have asked in your question

I will follow a very simple approach

```
value = 1.23.to_s.split('.') -> ["1", "23"]
value.last.to_i -> "23"
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything... I feel the best answer is `(num - num.to_i).abs` because it also works for negative numbers.

e.g.

(1.23 - 1.23.to_i).abs = 0.23

(-1.23 - -1.23.to_i).abs = 0.23

Comment: This will give you imprecision. Bad approach. Example: (37319.70-37319.70.to_i).abs
=> 0.6999999999970896