# show only decimal value in floating point number using sprintf

Tags: ruby, printf

I'm been trying to get only decimal point value of a floating point number here are my sceanrio

```
21.95 => .95

22.00 => .00
```

I try do it using following regex

> \.\d{2}

I even had other solution

```
number = 21.96.round(2)

precision = number - number.to_i
```

Or

```
"." + number.to_s.split('.')[1]
```

But I'm just not able to find it via `sprintf` which is what I want

Comment: @CarySwoveland the OP is looking for a solution using `sprintf` which returns strings.

Comment: @Stefan, considering that the OP first tried to use a regex, I figure this is an XY question with the current focus being on `sprintf`, but I will ask (and will delete my earlier comment.

Comment: Ratatouille, is your question how to convert the float `21.95` to the string `".95" `, or how to do that using `sprintf`? Your first line is confusing because `.95` is not shown in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You can only get the decimal part using the module function. Here is a solution using sprintf

```
a = 1001.123123
sprintf("%.2f", a.modulo(1))
# prints 0.12
```

Without sprintf,

```
a = 1001.123123
puts a.modulo(1).round(2)
# prints 0.12
```

Related question to get the fraction part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406032/get-fraction-part-of-a-decimal-number) and more about the [modulo function here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-modulo).

Comment: The OP wants `.12`, not `0.12`

Comment: Note that you have to use `a.abs.modulo(1)` when dealing with negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think its best to approach this problem from a char point of view.
First convert your double to an array of chars, then check each character if the value of that character  is a ".".
Next you just put the following characters into a string and output these in sprintf.